# Как передать данные из активити в фрагменты

Tags: activity, android-fragment, android-intent, android-bundle

я посмотрел этот ответ но он мне не понятен
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392261/android-pass-dataextras-to-a-fragment

По нескольким причинам, почему не кидать интент? 
куда разместить код приема данных из бандла во фрагменте, как мне найти нужный фрагмент если у меня TabView и адаптер соотвественно, прицеплять тэги?

Задача, 
Данные: 
Ретрофит, RxJava, 1 главное активити с таб вью, 3 фрагмента в таб вью.

Что происходит:
В главном активити, делается АСИНХРОННЫЙ запрос на сервер, возвращается обьект,
когда обьект вернулся им наполняется глобальная переменная ArrayList, 
и вызывается функция сортировки, функция создает 3 новых листа из предыдущего и должна сунуть их фрагментам а те в свою очередь строят кард вью из того что им пришло.

Как это сделать (передать обьект во фрагмент при асинхронном выполнении)? ведь это событие по своей сути, оно может произойти когда угодно, а приложение это не микроконтроллер где есть бесконечный цикл по которому вертится программа и ты знаешь что вот сейчас то она и проверит если есть данные (на новой итерации).

есть несколько вариантов примерно, но я туда не копал, поэтому не знаю что лучше.

1. шаред преференцес
2. контент провайдер
3. интент
4. бандл
5. MVP паттерн (правда не знаю что это пока что)) ).

Посоветуйте как лучше сделать, получается когда приложение стартует, сразу по умолчанию показывается первый фрагмент, и через табы можно листать и видеть что в остальных.

Хотелось бы просто отправить бандл когда вызовется функция окончания приема данных, но как его принять, не в onCreateView же и onActivityCreated не поможет,
естьь идея повесить во фрагменете EVENT на изменение бандла и там обновлять адаптер фрагмента и размещать элементы, это реально? можно увидеть примерный скетч, или статью да что угодно).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Интерфейс

   ```
   public interface CompleteListener 
   {
   void onComplete(Object object);
   }
   ```
2. Manager

public class CompleteManager {

```
public static CompleteListener listener;

public static void callComplete(Object object) {
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onComplete(object);
    }
}
```

}
3. Во фрагменте:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    CompleteManager.listener = object -> {do smth with object}
```

4. Вызов из активити:

   ```
   CompleteManager.callComplete(object);
   ```